# Aggregating data in a tf.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a problem aggregating rows and transforming rows in a tf.data.Dataset.
Each row have an string `id` and a string `category` where some categories are subcategories of others.
I want to transform the dataset by mapping each category value to a `one hot` encoding of the base categories and then grouping them by `id` and summing up the `one hot` encodings

I can combine multiple rows using `tf.data.experimental.group_by_reducer` but I can not for the life of me figure out how to map them them to one hot encodings before reducing them.

Any help would be appriciated.

So far I have tried using `tf.one_hot`, but it does not work with strings.
I've also tried to implement a `tf.lookup.StaticHashTable` but could not get it to work with tensors as values, it complained about shape.

Unfortunately the code was written in a notebook and is gone now...

Regards

Comment: What code have you written to try to do this and what are the results?

Comment: the code so far has just been trying to not get errors in jupyter and failing